# AngularJS Input Auto Focus

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

currently I'm learning the AngularJS. I have a problem in autofocusing an element.

My idea is:

***If a span element is clicked, it is hid and it triggers the input element to appear (with autofocus).***

Here is the code that I've made so far:

```
<table>
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Words</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tr>
                <td ng-if="!edit" class="animate-if">
                    <span ng-click="$parent.edit = true" style="border: none;">  Some words </span>
                </td>
                <td ng-if="edit" class="animate-if">
                    <input type="text" value="Some words" ng-blur="$parent.edit = false" style="background: #d7d7d7;">  
                </td>
            </tr>
</table>
```

I have it working, but the input text element is not automatically focused immediately after it appears. I've read some reference in show/hide and autofocusing input text element using directive. But they don't really helpful for me.

Thanks for your response.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
 <input type="text" value="Some words" ng-focus="$parent.edit = true" ng-show="$parent.edit = true" style="background: #d7d7d7;">
```